# How to Xdebug multiple sites hosted on my local machine that make requests to each other (in PhpStorm)?

Tags: php, api, rest, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm attempting to get Xdebug working with PhpStorm on multiple sites. Say I have 2 sites both being served in the same vagrant VM on my local machine:

http://my-app.dev (makes requests to the API below, xdebug is working)
  http://my-rest-api.dev (receives requests, but xdebug is not working)

My App makes requests to my rest API. When I visit http://my-app.dev in my browser, Xdebug is working correctly in PhpStorm for that project. I'll also have the API project open in PhpStorm as well. When I set breakpoints in the API project they are never hit (even though my App is successfully making requests to this API). The only way I can get the breakpoints to work in the API is if I open a browser tab and type in the API's endpoints directly into the address bar. I know there are extensions I can use to test API endpoints, but this is not convenient at all, since the requests would be cumbersome to build manually each time.

Both projects are set in PhpStorm to `listen to PHP debug connections`. I also tried turning on `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1` in my xdebug.ini file on the VM server. I've also set `Max. simultaneous connections` to 10 in PhpStorm Debug preferences.

Any solution on how I can debug both these sites together? I think this is a question that would help a lot of developers.

Comment: Collect xdebug logs and see what is happening there. In theory it should work (from settings point of view).

Comment: have you checked the "Start listening for php debug connexion" icon near of the run icon ? This solution helped me. Could you check this documentation: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Simultaneous+debugging+sessions+with+PhpStorm